# Errormessage "network path not found" when opening a user control in designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm maintaining an older .net applicatio written in C# and when trying to open some (local saved) <del>forms</del> user controls in designer, it says the <del>form</del> control could not be opened because the network path is not found and a variable wasn't declared or assigned. Maybe these two errors are associated.

.net-Version is 4.6.2 and Visual Studio Version is 2017 (15.2) - but this also happened with latest Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Look at the base class of the form class, if anything different from Form.  Or any user controls used on the form.  Whatever they do, somewhere it is missing a `if (!DesignMode)` test to ensure that risky code cannot run at design-time.  If that doesn't help then debug it, start another instance of VS and attach it to the first; have it stop on any CLR exception.

Comment: Okay, I tried to check and my Form is a frame derived from the UserControl Class but I can't any risky code on the way from that frame to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have installed the  .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack.

If not you can download from the below link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: It is installed